How to improve performance of Redis when used as in memory database to store processed asynchronous messages
We have a spring boot application that waits for asynchronous data from multiple server.
The spring boot application listens to these asynchronous responses from multiple servers and process it store it in redis database.
We are facing performance issue when the processing of data is slow and there is a huge queue of thousands or million messaged to be processed.
We want to understand can we do anything in our spring boot application to improve the processing and storing the data in redis.
I am expecting some solution in spring boot code to improve performance.

I have read your question. This problem primarily involves handling a large amount of data received from many producers. You should reconsider using Kafka. Here is my main suggestions:

You publish a kafka topic. Producers continuously produce messages to this topic
In your Spring Boot application, you can create multiple consumers to handle this messages

